# Autolayout and Device Orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, device-orientation, autorotate

I am developing an application which `supports portrait and landscape modes`. I am using `auto layout to arrange my views`. As i have been reading many posts and i have realized that developers commonly use one among the following approaches.

**1. First approach:**

Implement the `UIViewController:updateConstraints` method and update constraints according to device orientation.

**2. Second approach:**

Implement the `UIViewController:viewWillLayoutSubviews` method and update constraints according to device orientation.

Could anyone please tell me what is the best approach to use ? I have been searching for a best practice to combine autorotation and auto layout and nothing yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use this UIViewController's method:

`- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;`

that is called upon rotation, and call `-setNeedsUpdateConstraints` from there.
If you need to do additional calculations or manage the contrainsts add

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    // do calculations if needed, like set constants
}
```

Comment: I believe there is no need to calculate constraints in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method because this can be done in the updateViewConstraints by checking the current device orientation.

Comment: maybe my answer is not clear, I meant that the calculations are to be done in updateViewContraints method.

Comment: I confirm that the calculations are to be done in updateViewContraints  method. But when i call setNeedsUpdateConstraints method in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method i realize that updateViewConstraints is called more than once.

Comment: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation is depreciated. Use "viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)" instead. But consider that updateViewConstraints will be called before the view changes.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach is to use neither. Instead, configure your constraints correctly so that no programmatic changes are required on rotation. The Auto Layout runtime will maintain the views in position as you already have specified.

Updating constraints other than changing the value of `.constant` is a real performance hit and should be avoided.

Using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is not necessary. Auto Layout methods are `updateViewConstraints` (for the view controller), and `updateConstraints` (in the views).

Comment: But sometimes configuring the constraints is not enough because the layout aspect can totally change when switching from landscape to portrait and vice versa.

Comment: in that case, you will need one of the update constraints methods as described in the answer above by @Fr4ncis

Comment: just saw this come up. It might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772922/can-i-use-autolayout-to-provide-different-constraints-for-landscape-and-portrait

Comment: Yes i have just seen it and i think it is similar to @Fr4ncis solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best approach is to update the constraints in `-(void)updateViewConstraints` by checking the device orientation. There is no need to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` because it is automatically called by the iOs when the device orientation changes. Thank you all for the great effort.

Answer (score 0):

for ios8+

From the documentation for:

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection
          withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

> A standard view controller might use this method to change the
>   constraints on the views it manages.