# Various autolayout constraints for different device orientations programmatically and without size classes?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, autolayout, constraints

The question is similar to this one:
[Autolayout and Device Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346573/autolayout-and-device-orientation)

But `updateViewConstraints` is never called (because nothing from mentioned methods is called on rotation, tested on iOS 9.1 simulator). In general it seems this topic doesn't contain a correct answer or the answers are too old.

I can't use size classes because the project should have also iOS 7 support and it supports size classes but with huge limitations.

It seems I need to clear and recreate all the constraints on each rotation event:

1)which method should recreate constraints?

2)how to recreate them at all? Maybe I remove them incorrectly:

```
for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews)
{
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}
for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews)
{
    [v removeConstraints:v.constraints];
    [self.view removeConstraints:v.constraints];
}
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
```

Or could you suggest a better way how to fix this issue?

Comment: How are you creating them in the first place ? The correct way is to either modify certain constraints, or completely remove some (or all) and re-create them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two different sets of constraints programatically on viewDidLoad and only activate the ones you want to use

```
myPortraitConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someItem, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10
myPortraitConstraint.active = true

myLandscapeConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someItem, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0
myLandscapeConstraint.active = false
```

then on a rotation event switch the constraints you wish to use

```
myPortraitConstraint.active = false
myLandscapeConstraint.active = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```