# Xcode 6 auto layout different constraints for portrait and landscape orientation

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, orientation, constraints

Is there a way by which the constraints I give in portrait orientation DO NOT apply in landscape orientation and vice versa.

I am working on an app which has a lot of small images and text fields on the screen.
I need to give different positions and coordinates when these are in Portrait and Landscape orientation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use autolayout to provide different constraints for landscape and portrait orientations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772922/can-i-use-autolayout-to-provide-different-constraints-for-landscape-and-portrait)

Answer (score 3):

With iOS8/Xcode6 there are **Size Classes**.

Here's all the magic:
With the same storyboard, you can set different constraints for different kind of device, with no code.

*(Click to enlarge)*
[image: storyboard with any size class]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/minis/2015/04/1422007610-capture-d-ecran-2015-01-23-a-10-46-58.png))</sub>

[image: storyboard with compact width size class]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/minis/2015/04/1422007610-capture-d-ecran-2015-01-23-a-10-45-00.png))</sub>

On the left, the regular layout. On the right, the layout when there's a compact width.

You can see that the bottom bar turns blue when you are in a specific size class, meaning you only make changes on that particular size class.