# Autolayout bug with UIAlertView/Controller?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uialertview, nslayoutconstraint, uialertcontroller

I am trying to switch the Autolayout constraints of my project for each orientation and am doing so by programmatically removing and adding a portrait and landscape set of [NSAutoLayoutConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html). I have the correct auto layout constraints (I think) for the layout for both orientations. My storyboard is **not** using Size Classes for compatibility.

I have taken screenshots of the correct layouts. The red portion is a UIView colored red.

[image: portrait screenshot]
Portrait layout

[image: landscape screenshot]
Landscape layout

My viewWillLayoutSubviews: is

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [self.termToolbar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
}
```

and all the constraints adding and removing is in `updateViewConstraints`

When starting the app in portrait orientation and then rotating to landscape, I get a constraint error:

```
2015-07-26 10:50:42.856 reproduce[1084:23311] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x786436c0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7864cb70(20)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x78643680 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7864cb70]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7864ca90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78657bc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7864ca90(480)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78657bf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7864ca90(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x786593c0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7864cb70]-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x78a21a70]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x786593f0 V:[UISearchBar:0x78a21a70]-(0)-[UITableView:0x7982aa00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78659420 V:[UITableView:0x7982aa00]-(0)-[UIView:0x78a216f0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78620570 V:[UIView:0x78a216f0]-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x78b81d00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x786205a0 V:[UIToolbar:0x78b81d00]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7864ca90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x786590a0 UIView:0x78a216f0.height == 0.75*UIView:0x78a216f0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x786596d0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x78a216f0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7864ca90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78659720 H:[UIView:0x78a216f0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7864ca90 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x786593f0 V:[UISearchBar:0x78a21a70]-(0)-[UITableView:0x7982aa00]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Note that I am rotating from portrait to landscape and the error shown are for the **portrait orientation**! When rotating from landscape to portrait, no debug output/error occurs. Rotating back to landscape causes the same error.

Even with these errors, the view layout appears fine for both portrait and landscape until I show a UIAlertView/Controller. Once an alert is shown, the layout fails and **both** portrait and landscape layouts are displayed wrong (UITableView disappears, red UIView takes up whole screen, etc). It doesn't matter **if the alert is dismissed or still being presented**, the layout will fail everytime after the alert.

I created a sample project to reproduce this behavior that can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0BmSjMD7XdjZ0I4Tk54QWd6MzQ/view?usp=sharing). UI Element outlets are connected in IB.  All the code is in the default ViewController class. Any idea why this behavior is occurring or is this a bug in AutoLayout for a simple layout change between orientations? Thanks.

Portrait constraints:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05cda0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7b0648a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05cc30 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7b0648a0]-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05cc00 V:[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]-(0)-[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05cbd0 V:[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]-(0)-[UIView:0x7b0e9210]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05cba0 V:[UIView:0x7b0e9210]-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05cb70 V:[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05ced0 UIView:0x7b0e9210.height == 0.75*UIView:0x7b0e9210.width>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c990 H:|-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c940 H:[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c8a0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7b0e9210]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c850 H:[UIView:0x7b0e9210]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c780 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c730 H:[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c6c0 H:|-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c670 H:[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>
```

Landscape constraints:

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c530 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7b0648a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c4e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7b0648a0]-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c4b0 V:[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]-(0)-[UIView:0x7b0e9210]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c480 V:[UIView:0x7b0e9210]-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c450 V:[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c290 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7b0648a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c240 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7b0648a0]-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c210 V:[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]-(0)-[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c1e0 V:[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c1b0 V:[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05bf70 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05bf20 H:[UITableView:0x7cb4d600]-(0)-[UIView:0x7b0e9210]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05bef0 H:[UIView:0x7b0e9210]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05c2f0 UIView:0x7b0e9210.height == 0.75*UIView:0x7b0e9210.width>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05be30 H:|-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05bde0 H:[UISearchBar:0x7b0e9590]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05bd70 H:|-(0)-[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b05bd20 H:[UIToolbar:0x7b069f10]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b064990 )>
```

Comment: "I have the correct auto layout constraints" No you don't! You wouldn't be getting an error if you did. The error is pretty clear. You've over-determined your constraints. You've got vertical constraints, you've got horizontal constraints, and then you've got this rule that one particular view's height is always exactly 3/4 of its width. You can't have all of them; that view needs room to change its aspect ratio if you are going to pin everything all the way down and all the way across like this.

Comment: The 4:3 aspect ratio is for the red UIView. I am still not seeing the conflict between my constraints though. Shouldn't the tableview grow/shrink to fit the red UIView in both orientations? (Also, why is the debugger complaining about the constraints that I'm removing???)

Comment: @matt Okay so my constraints are wrong and are causing errors. Could you provide an example of how my constraints are not fitting together? 
I made the constraints with my ideal layout in mind and I don't see how the constraints could conflict on the iPhone screen size so perhaps my mental image is not accounting for all possible conflicts in the layout. 
I have added a list of my programmatic portrait and landscape constraints to the question. Thanks.

Comment: So the constraint debug error is thrown before `updateViewConstraints` where I swap my constraints...I think that is the problem. Where should I be setting my new constraints?
I was going according to this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772922/can-i-use-autolayout-to-provide-different-constraints-for-landscape-and-portrait
but apparently putting the update code in `updateViewConstraints` isn't right. Right now I can band-aid patch this by calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` after the constraints have been set a first time, but not too optimal... :(

Comment: "Could you provide an example of how my constraints are not fitting together?" I don't have to - that is what the layout engine is doing!

Comment: "Where should I be setting my new constraints?" Good question. Why are you setting new constraints at all? What's the goal here?

Comment: The goal is the get the desired layout shown in the screenshots above for both orientations without Size Classes. I am setting new constraints because I cannot find a set of NSLayoutConstraints that satisfy my layout requirements for both portrait and landscape (AFAIK). I have seen many SO posts mention changing constraints in `updateViewConstraints`. As I mentioned the OS throws errors for the portrait constraints when I rotate to landscape but the errors are before the `updateViewConstraints` method is run. Is this the correct way to do things?

Comment: Is this on iPhone only or is this a Universal app where you want to do this also on iPad? I ask because that makes a difference with regard to what events you will get on rotation.

Comment: This will be a Universal app.

Comment: Okay. Then your best moment to do this from the view controller is either `viewWillTransitionToSize:` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Perform the constraint-swapping right there (i.e. do not use `updateViewConstraints`).

Comment: This is an example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p256rotationChangesInterface2/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.swift But in that code I am using `willTransitionToTraitCollection:` - you can't do that because you won't get that call on an iPad when the user rotates. Note that this is because Apple would prefer you not change the interface on rotation on an iPad (but of course you _can_).

Comment: Doing the constraint change in `viewWillTransitionToSize:` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews:` works, but the "orientation" returned is the old orientation since they are called before the layout system tries to reposition everything so I will need to figure out the new orientation dimensions myself. Too bad Size Classes seem like the way to go for supporting multiple sets of the constraints in the future but lose iOS 6 support. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, but now you're raising a completely different issue. This is the first time you've mentioned the problem of backwards compatibility all the way to iOS 6 - do you realize that? So this is really a question about that, but you never _asked_ about that. I mean, I've got advice about that, but I haven't said anything because that's not what your question is. If that's really the question, I would suggest deleting this question and starting over.

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean about the "orientation returned". In `viewWillTransitionToSize:`, for example, you look at the upcoming size (which is the parameter) and the present size (which is simply your current bounds size) and you can easily know what is about to happen by looking to see, in each case, which is larger, the width or the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also filed an Apple Bug Report and TSI for this and got good answers back.

The solution for a method *called before the device's returned orientation changes* depends on what iOS versions you want to support.

**iOS < 8** [`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:)

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

**iOS 8+** [`viewWillTransitionToSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:)
and some checks to determine which orientation we are in.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    if (size.width < size.height && self.view.bounds.size.width > self.view.bounds.size.height) {
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:landscapeConstraints];
    } else if (size.width > size.height && self.view.bounds.size.width < self.view.bounds.size.height) {
        [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:portraitConstraints];
    }
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```