# How to use different constraint for landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to use different layout on landscape and portrait,

but always got warning about it.

My target :
[image]

my solution:

Add general constraint :

```
   View A Left   = SuperView Left
   View A Top    = SuperView Top
   View A Bottom = SuperView Bottom

   View B Right  = SuperView Right 
   View B Top    = SuperView Top 
   View B Bottom = SuperView Bottom 
   View B Left   = View A Right
```

Add landscape constraint :

```
View A width =  superview Height + 30
```

Add portrait constraint :

```
View A width = superView width
```

Then,

In `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` call `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];`

In `updateViewConstraints` 
set constraint active YES to landscape/portrait and also set NO to another constraint.

when I run the app, it workable,
bur I got some warning:

```
UITableView = View A, 
UIView (0x13ed098c0) = superView
UIView (0x174287080) = View B

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174287030 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x13ed098c0(568)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174287080 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x13ed098c0(239)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17428a960 UITableView:0x13f0b2000.width == UIView:0x13ed098c0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170284dd0 UITableView:0x13f0b2000.width == UIView:0x13ed098c0.height + 30>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174287080 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x13ed098c0(239)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How can I make it work without warning?

Thanks,

Comment: Please refer this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772922/can-i-use-autolayout-to-provide-different-constraints-for-landscape-and-portrait

Comment: Yes, but can I use it with program only?

Comment: This can be done easily using both size classes and auto layout in the interface builder itself.