# iOS: AVPlayerViewController view not removing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I created a sample video app using `AVPlayerViewController`. It is working fine. But the problems are after finishing the video the `AVPlayerViewController` view is not removing. Other problem is set the constraints for `AVPlayerViewController` for portrait default size in landscape mode full screen. I am new for constraints. Please download the project and run the project logger shows the constraint problems.

Source code project : http://www.filedropper.com/avplayerdemos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problem with your code:

```
asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler: ^{
    dispatch_async(
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       if (!asset.playable) {
                           return;
                       } else {
                           [self prepareToPlayAsset: asset withRequestedKeys: requestedKeys];
                       }

                       if (videoPlayerItem) {
                           [videoPlayerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kkStatusKey];
                           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                                           name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                                         object: videoPlayerItem];
                       }
                   });
}];
```

this code above you add observer and remove after. so should change two:

```
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler: ^{
    dispatch_async(
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                       if (videoPlayerItem) {
                           [videoPlayerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kkStatusKey];
                           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                                           name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                                         object: videoPlayerItem];
                       }


                       if (!asset.playable) {
                           return;
                       } else {

                           [self prepareToPlayAsset: asset withRequestedKeys: requestedKeys];
                       }



                   });
}];
```

Problem 2:

```
- (void)prepareToPlayAsset: (AVURLAsset *)asset withRequestedKeys: (NSArray *)requestedKeys {
     for (NSString *thisKey in requestedKeys) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:thisKey error:&error];

        switch (keyStatus) {
            case AVKeyValueStatusUnknown:
                NSLog(@"%@ AVKeyValueStatusUnknown", thisKey);
            break;

            case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Error! PlayAsset failed.\nAVKey : %@.\nError: %@", thisKey, error);
                return;
            break;

            case AVKeyValueStatusLoading:
                NSLog(@"%@ AVKeyValueStatusLoading", thisKey);
            break;
            case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"%@ AVKeyValueStatusCancelled", thisKey);
            break;
            case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded: {

                videoPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];
                [videoPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath: kkStatusKey options:0 context:nil];

                videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: videoPlayerItem];

                /**
                 * Creating the videoAdplayer through passing the avplayer object
                */
                [self createVideoPlayer: videoPlayer];

                if ([thisKey isEqualToString: @"duration"]) {

                } else if ([thisKey isEqualToString: @"tracks"]) {
                    NSLog(@"\n\n asset.tracks : %@ \n\n", asset.tracks);
                } else if ([thisKey isEqualToString: @"metadata"]) {
                    NSLog(@"\n\n assetMetadata : %@ \n\n", asset.metadata);
                }
            }
            break;

            default:
            break;
         }
    }

    if (!asset.playable) {
        return;
    }
}
```

In this loop just check eveything load and return if have failed. In this case have 2 key, you code like this will add two `childviewcontroller` and it will play two item player. So change code to it:

```
- (void)prepareToPlayAsset: (AVURLAsset *)asset withRequestedKeys: (NSArray *)requestedKeys {
   for (NSString *thisKey in requestedKeys) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:thisKey error:&error];

        switch (keyStatus) {
            case AVKeyValueStatusUnknown:
                NSLog(@"%@ AVKeyValueStatusUnknown", thisKey);
            break;

            case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Error! PlayAsset failed.\nAVKey : %@.\nError: %@", thisKey, error);
                return;
            break;

            case AVKeyValueStatusLoading:
                 NSLog(@"%@ AVKeyValueStatusLoading", thisKey);
            break;
            case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"%@ AVKeyValueStatusCancelled", thisKey);
            break;
            case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded: {


            }
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
     }

     videoPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];
     [videoPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath: kkStatusKey options:0 context:nil];

    videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem: videoPlayerItem];

    /**
     * Creating the videoAdplayer through passing the avplayer object
     */
     [self createVideoPlayer: videoPlayer];



    if (!asset.playable) {
        return;
    }
}
```

I pretty sure that with your demo. Change like this, it will work ok.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It's working. One doubt, if I written the code in AVKeyValueStatusLoaded  what is the problem? as well as Can you help on constraints?

Comment: You can check with code add in AVKeyValuStatusLoaded you will see problem. About constraint you can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772922/can-i-use-autolayout-to-provide-different-constraints-for-landscape-and-portrait

Comment: Hello bro @vienvu, could you help me my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132122/avplayer-rotate-view-makes-cannot-tap-to-the-screen ?