# Autolayout : Button side by side in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, visual-format-language

I am facing a problem in design a view using `autolayout` where I have four buttons line by line in `portrait` mode of the device but I want two buttons side by side in `landscape` orientation. How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hope this helps ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772922/can-i-use-autolayout-to-provide-different-constraints-for-landscape-and-portrait

Comment: I agree with with previous commenter you should use size classes for your purpose. But on certain cases you could pull it off using UICollectionView. By setting button sizes on orientation change. If you size it just right such that button 2 reach the end of the screen, button 3 and 4 will automatically flow on the next row using default UICollectionViewFlowLayout